# ACF Taxonomy in Loop

Tags: taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

How are you?

My problem is the following on my front page I'm displaying some cards, for example name and description, this information is from my taxonomy called event because I created some fields with ACF and I would like to print them inside the card but I don't know how to do it .

Below I'm putting the code on how I'm printing the cards

```php
    <?php if(is_front_page()):
    $terms = get_terms(
        [
            'taxonomy'   => 'evento',
            'hide_empty' => false,
        ]
    );
    if (!empty( $terms ) && is_array( $terms ) ):
        foreach ( $terms as $term ): ?>

            <div class="col-lg-3 mb-5">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $term->name; ?></h5>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="card-text">Date:</li>
                            <li class="card-text">Horário: </li>
                            <li class="card-text"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) ?>" class="btn btn-primary" title="<?php the_title_attribute( 'before=Saiba mais: "&after="' ); ?>">Saiba mais</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach;
    endif;
?>

<?php else:?>
    <p><?php _e('xxxxxx'); ?></p>
<?php endif;?>
```

I need to print the values
`initial_date` and `end_date`
Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Hello Rodrigo - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! Unfortunately, questions regarding third-party products are presently [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackeschange.com/help/on-topic) here. The best course of action would be to pose this question in ACF's official support channels (or an associated community). I believe this information is also covered in ACF's Getting Started guides - for tax term meta specifically, the `get_field()`/`the_field()` documentation will detail how to retrieve field data attached to terms.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do something like this?

```
$initDate = get_field('initial_date',$term);
echo $initDate;
```